# Brackets on a line

Tags: arrows, brackets, line

I am trying to replicate a figure like the following. But I haven't found the way to draw a line between the brackets or to align the arrow with that line.

Any help would be most welcome :)

[image]

Thanks in advance and a happy New Year !

Yann

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX and a happy New Year to you as well! There are a lot of ways to draw this. Do you have some packages in mind which you would like to use? You could use [PGF/Ti*k*Z](https://tikz.dev) for instance, but it depends on the context whether this is the best solution in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply Jasper. I have never had to draw figures on LaTeX, so I had no clue what package to explore. Searching for solutions, I have only found math-related posts. I guess the best solution in my case would be the less technically demanding, as I'm a newbie (mostly using LaTeX for text and tables). I will have a look at PGF/TikZ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a Ti*k*Z version to get you started. Many adjustments are possible.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[{Bracket[width=4mm]}-{Bracket[width=4mm]}](0,0)--(1,0);
\draw[Triangle-Triangle](1,0)--node[above=2mm]{text1}node[below]{text2}(2,0);
\draw[{Bracket[width=4mm]}-](2,0)--(2.01,0)node[right]{$T_0$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That will be very useful.